# Variable-Resolution Van der Corput Sequence

Tags: python, algorithm, sampling

I'm seeking to perform a [Van der Corput](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Corput_sequence)-like sampling of a range, but with a custom resolution.

As an example, consider sampling the range `[0, 100]`, with a resolution of 25. This would entail sampling at `[0, 25, 50, 75, 100]`, and if we follow a Van der Corput-like sequence, something like: `[0, 100, 50, 25, 75]`.

Each "pass" of the Van der Corput algorithm iteratively divides the range into segments `1/2` the size of the previous pass (2 points, then 3, 5, 9, 17, ...). So if my minimum resolution is `24`, then I would need `2^n + 1` (in this case, 9) samples, rather than `ceil(100/24) = 5` samples in order to achieve the desired resolution.

Are there any approaches that yield the solution I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think your sequence has a minor flaw, `100` is never part of that sequence. The *Van der Corput sequence* should be *0, 50, 25, 75, ...*.

A *Van der Corput sequence* shows an interesting pattern if we look at the binary fractions of the number. In essence it boils down to:

```
binary    decimal     binary reverse
0.0       0.0           0.0
0.1       0.5           1.0
0.01      0.25         10.0
0.11      0.75         11.0
0.001     0.125       100.0
0.101     0.625       101.0
0.011     0.375       110.0
0.111     0.875       111.0
```

the binary reverse mirrors the number over the "*binary point*". So here we see that this is actually just a binary counter.

We can use that logic to generate the `i`-th element of the sequence for a given range with `l` and `u` the integral lower and upperbound respectively:

```
def vdc_seq(i, l, u):
    v = 0
    p = 0
    d = u - l
    while i:
        v <<= 1
        if i & 1:
            v += d
        i >>= 1
        p += 1
    if p:
        v += (1 << p-1)
    return l + v >> p
```

For example:

```
>>> list(map(partial(vdc_seq, l=0, u=100), range(9)))
[0, 50, 25, 75, 13, 63, 38, 88, 6]
```

We can easily use floating points here, by replacing this:

```
def vdc_seq(i, l, u):
    v = 0
    p = 1
    d = u - l
    while i:
        v <<= 1
        if i & 1:
            v += d
        i >>= 1
        p <<= 1
    return l + v / p
```

The "resolution" of the *2<sup>k+1</sup>-1*-th element is *2<sup>-k</sup>*, so for a given minimal resolution `m`, we can determine when to stop, and generate a list like:

```
from functools import partial

def vdc_seq_list_min(l, u, m):
    n = 2 * (u - l + m - 1) // m - 1
    return map(partial(vdc_seq, l=l, u=u), range(n))
```

For example:

```
>>> list(vdc_seq_list_min(0, 100, 24))
[0, 50, 25, 75, 13, 63, 38, 88, 6]
>>> list(vdc_seq_list_min(0, 100, 10))
[0, 50, 25, 75, 13, 63, 38, 88, 6, 56, 31, 81, 19, 69, 44, 94, 3, 53, 28, 78]
```

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive reply! Could you please explain in more detail why you are ANDing i and 1, and what p is doing in vdc_seq?

Comment: @Teknophilia: with `i & 1` we check the last digit, `p` is the number of digits we need to shift back, we first calculate the value times 2^p, and then divide it. We do this to do all the arithmetic in the "integer world" since in languages as Haskell and Python, such integers can store values of arbitrary size.

Comment: I see. Would there be a way to adjust the sequence generation so that rather than stopping at a resolution of 2 * (u - l + m - 1) // m - 1, we instead adjust the spacing of the points to achieve it? As an example, in my question I mentioned how using a vanilla VDC leads to having many more samples to check rather than simply dividing the range by the resolution (which of course doesn't provide the VDC "sampling order"). I've tried adding a padding when generating but that seems like the wrong approach.

Comment: @Teknophilia: but `2 * (u - l + m - 1) // m - 1` is not the resolution, `n` is the number of points. Furthermore I do not really understand what you aim to achieve this. The van der Corput sequence is, by the *Koksma-Hlawka theorem* a low discrepancy sequence that is typically used for quasi-Monte Carlo interpolation.